# Caching keys with tags in Redis, decreases performance

Tags: laravel, caching, redis

I am trying to cache user privileges. The thing is all users have certain common features (tags). So once the privilege corresponding to a user feature (tag) is modified, I intend to invalidate the cache of only those users sharing that particular feature (tag).

I have tried caching using tags in Laravel with Redis. It solves my purpose, but the performance degrades for a large number of users, which is a major concern for me.

Is there an alternative way to approach the caching in Laravel using Redis for the above-mentioned scenario?

Comment: What is the end result in here, I fail to understand the thing with user privileges, they change so often that it matters? Do you need to invalidate the cache immediately? Can it be done perhaps when less users are using the application? Do you invalidate whole cache for users (even the unrelated privileges) when just one of assigned do change? What does it mean performance hit, when? Only once until a user refreshes the page? Continuously during the "session" while user uses the app? How many users, how big is the cache per user? Have you tried increasing RAM for Redis?

Answer (score 1):

Generally, users are not directly linked with priveleges/permissions. In typical scenarios, users are linked to roles and roles are linked with permissions.

The user-role relationship is **not cached** and the role-permission relationship **is cached**. This is very beneficial since there may be thousands of users and caching all user-permission data would deteriorate performance, but there are likely to be 15-20 maybe 100 roles.

**Why does caching user-privilege relationships deteriorate performance?**

Pretty simple, caching only improves performance for data that is frequently accessed. If there are thousands or hundreds of thousands of users, caching all this user-permission relationship data will actually be worse than fetching from the database because it's frequently accessed.

Caching role-permission data on the other hand is likely to improve performance because of the high frequency of access (every user that's logged in will hit the cache for this data unlike user-privelege caching).

Hope this makes sense.

You can check out the caching implementation of the [Spatie Laravel Permission library](https://www.github.com/spatie/laravel-permission) which pretty much is on the same lines. It's currently the most popular Laravel library for roles and permissions.

See also: https://stackoverflow.com/a/42842077/7377984